# implement add_filter with LIKE %some_title% in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a filter to my WP_Query(below code) to search for post_title LIKE %some_title%

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => $page_size,
    'paged' => $page,
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'orderby'          => 'title', 
    'order'            => 'ASC',

  );

  $result = new WP_Query($args);
```

How to add a filter to match product title with $some_title?

Comment: Try this
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something

I think this is what you searching for.

Comment: @Hemc Can you help me understand the parameters of add_filter ( 'posts_where', 'wpse18703_posts_where', 10, 2 ); what is first and second parameter and what is 10, 2 ?

Answer (score 3):

you can try in this way

```
$query = "
        SELECT      *
        FROM        $wpdb->posts
        WHERE       $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$param2%'
        ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title
";
$wpdb->get_results($query);
```

alternate way and standard way

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse18703_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function wpse18703_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wpse18703_title = $wp_query->get( 'wpse18703_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'' . esc_sql( like_escape( $wpse18703_title ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

use in this way

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'wpse18703_title' => 'your string',
    'posts_per_page' => $page_size,
    'paged' => $page,
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'orderby'          => 'title', 
    'order'            => 'ASC',

  );
 $result = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: pls explain the parameters of add_filter ( 'posts_where', 'wpse18703_posts_where', 10, 2 ); what is first and second parameter and what is 10, 2 ?

Comment: @rao priority, accepted arguments and for more refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: how to add this filter to my wp_query?

Comment: you can call WP_Query, you just pass the title as the wpse18703_title argument

Comment: Still don't get it, could you pls show me how to use my wp_query along with your add_filter function in one code?

Comment: i think you it will better for you to go with first one it easy for you. for second you have enough knowledge of wordpress.